# Search page pagination does not work

Tags: pagination, search

I am working on a custom theme. My issue is that when I use the search form it will show the search results as it is suppose to but when I use the pagination on the page it just takes me back to my home page.

I have wordpress installed in a wordpress sub-directory that is accessible from /blog. I have a static front page (front-page.php) and blog page (home.php) and the site works fine for the most part. I am having a few issues with post per page on the initial blog page but I already have a question for that posted on this site.

This issue is that the search page works on the initial search submission but the pagination does not maintain the /search/%s format.

**EDIT**
I was able to get it to work by changing the form `method="post"` to `method="get"` but this appends the ?s=%s I would like to keep this with clean URLs if possible so I am leaving this open still until I can figure this out.

I have provided my code below:

**search.php**

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying Search Results pages.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage EHRScopev2
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>      

<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <h2 class="home-label"><?php printf(__('Search Results for: %s', 'ehrscope'), '<strong><em>' . get_search_query() . '</em></strong>'); ?></h2>
        <?php
        /* Run the loop to output the page.
        * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
        * called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.
        */
        get_template_part('loop', 'single');
        ?>
        <div class="page-nav">
            <?php if (get_next_posts_link()) { ?>
            <span class="nav-button older-posts"><?php next_posts_link( '&laquo; Older posts'); ?></span>
            <?php 
            }
            if (get_previous_posts_link()) { ?>
            <span class="nav-button newer-posts"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &raquo;' ); ?></span>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>       
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**searchform.php**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" class="search-form" role="search">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="s" value="<?php echo (is_search()) ? get_search_query() : __('Search...', 'ehrscope'); ?>" />
        <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="<?php _e('Submit', 'ehrscope'); ?>"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**loop-single.php**

```
<?php
/**
* The loop that displays a single post.
*
* The loop displays the posts and the post content. See
* http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop to understand it and
* http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags to understand
* the tags used in it.
*
* This can be overridden in child themes with loop-single.php.
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage EHRScopev2
*/
?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-holder">
                <div class="box-frame">
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        <em class="meta"><?php ehrscope_posted_on(); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span class="total-comments"><?php comments_popup_link(); ?></span></em>
                        <?php
                        if (!is_single() && has_excerpt()):
                            the_excerpt();
                        else:
                            the_content(__('Continue reading', 'ehrscope') . ': <em>' . the_title('', '', false) . '</em>');
                        endif;
                        ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <?php
                        if (is_single()):
                            ehrscope_wp_link_pages();
                            $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                            ?>
                            <p class="entry-meta"><?php ehrscope_show_tags(); ?></p>
                            <?php if ($tags): ?>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggle-related-posts" class="button"><?php _e('Show Related Posts', 'ehrscope'); ?></a>
                                <?php
                            endif;
                        endif;
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if (is_single()): ?>
            <div class="box" id="related-posts-cage">
                <div class="box-holder">
                    <div class="box-frame">
                        <div>
                            <?php if (is_single()): ?>
                                <?php
                                if ($tags):
                                    $tag_ids = array();
                                    foreach ($tags as $individual_tag) {
                                        $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
                                    }
                                    $args = array(
                                        'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                                        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                                        'posts_per_page' => 10, // Number of related posts to display.
                                        'caller_get_posts' => 1
                                    );
                                    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                                    if ($my_query->have_posts()):
                                        ?>
                                        <h3><?php _e('Related Posts', 'ehrscope'); ?></h3>
                                        <ul>
                                            <?php
                                            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
                                                ?>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                                    &nbsp;
                            <!--                                                <span class="related-posts-date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?></span>-->
                                                </li>
                                                    <?php
                                            endwhile;
                                            ?>
                                        </ul>
                                        <?php
                                    endif;
                                endif;
                            endif;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php
        endif;
        comments_template('', true);
    endwhile;
else:
    ?>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-holder">
            <div class="box-frame">
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                    <h2><?php _e('No Results', 'ehrscope'); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'ehrscope'); ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Did you try to add the pagination inside the loop? Not outside it?

Answer (score -1):

```
   <form method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/customsearch.php" class="search-form" role="search"> ... </form>
```

customsearch.php in content :

http://pastebin.com/mxVPphXa

customsearch.php should be here: yoursite.com/dir/customsearch.php

Comment: same issue. The search results show fine but the pagination does not maintain the search term and just goes back to the fron-page. Thanks though